# Why doesn't read permission on directories reveal inode numbers?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, directory, inode

As far as I understand, the "read" permission on directories allows one to list all *names* under that directory, and no more than that.

Based on common understanding of FS design, if a directory is stored as a file, its content should at least contain, in addition to the file names, a reference to their inodes. Using the "everything is a file" philosophy of Unix, the "read" permission grants access to the "file content" of the directory itself, and thus *should* be sufficient to retrieve the inode numbers of each file. However, this is not the case.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You mean something like `ls -i -1 *`, or `stat -c '%i %n' *` ? (Much of what `stat` can report is *in* the inode itself, but obviously the inode number cannot be).

Comment: @Paul_Pedant it seems that more can be done than `stat` and `ls` can do. Probably not much more. See muru`s answer.

Answer (score 26):

As [@muru has shown](/a/742875), you can definitely get the inode numbers (on any POSIX system, not just Linux) by reading the directory contents (whether directories are implemented as normal files like in the early Unices or not).

What probably caused you to think you couldn't was that you tried

```
ls -i dir
```

On a directory for which you had *read* but not *search* permission and saw:

```
file1: Permission denied
file2: Permission denied
```

That's because your `ls` implementation did try to do a `lstat()` on each of the entries returned by `readdir()` instead of just printing the `d_ino` in the entry.

Not all implementations do that. For instance, the `ls` builtin of ksh93 (if included at build time and enabled with `builtin ls`) does print the `d_ino` as returned by `readdir()` rather than `lstat()`ing each file.

One reason why most `ls` implementations use `lstat()` to retrieve the inode number may be that otherwise, you generally get the wrong inode numbers for files that are mount points:

```
% ksh93 -o emacs
$ builtin ls
$ /bin/ls -i /
    21 bin        28 home-blank       6 lost+found      22 root       5 tmp
     2 boot        9 home-test       26 media            1 run        2 u
     8 cdrom      14 lib             17 mnt             15 sbin      13 usr
     1 dev        23 lib32       855691 opt             25 snap  229376 var
    19 etc        20 lib64           34 pool0           18 srv
    34 home        4 libx32           1 proc             1 sys
$ ls -i /
    21 bin        28 home-blank       6 lost+found      22 root       5 tmp
    24 boot        9 home-test       26 media           12 run        2 u
     8 cdrom      14 lib             17 mnt             15 sbin      13 usr
     3 dev        23 lib32       855691 opt             25 snap  229376 var
    19 etc        20 lib64           11 pool0           18 srv
265966 home        4 libx32           7 proc            16 sys
```

See how for files that are mountpoints (like `/boot`, `/proc`, `/sys` above), ksh93's builtin `ls` gives the inode numbers of the files in the root filesystem, while `/bin/ls` (in my case GNU `ls`) gives the effective inode numbers of those files, that is that of the root directory of the mounted file systems.

In any case,  `ls -id some/file` will do a `lstat()` on the file (ksh93's `ls` actually does a `stat()` making it non-POSIX compliant).

```
$ ls -id /boot
     2 /boot
```

(with both ksh93 and GNU `ls`).

Answer (score 12):

It does, at least on a Linux system I tried it on:

Setup:

```
mkdir foo
touch foo/bar
# remove as much permission as possible, so that the program still works (only leave `r`).
chmod ugo-wx foo
chmod ugo+r #incase your umask, caused it not to be set
sudo chown root:root foo -R
```

And with:

```cpp
//readinode.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        auto dir = opendir(argv[i]);
        for(auto direntry = readdir(dir); direntry; direntry = readdir(dir))
        {
            std::cout << direntry->d_ino << ' ' << direntry->d_name << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

I get:

```
% ./readinode foo
3933790 .
3932162 ..
3933910 bar
```

Comment: It looks like `ls` and `stat` are doing more than this program. They then trigger an error and bail-out.

Comment: Why the `chown`? And why the `-w`? Neither of these are needed to demonstrate what you are saying. I repeated your experiment, and got same results (different inode numbers), without `root` or removing write permission.

Comment: Yes, neither are strictly necessary, but I'm just demonstrating that this works with minimal access.

Answer (score 3):

## "What am I missing"

Don't think the proposition that you don't get inode information is wrong - though the idea of inodes map differently to non-UNIX file systems.

But what I think you're missing is that you confuse *userland interface ideals* ("everything's a file") with *implementation detail*:

I'd say you're simply trying to take the assumptions on the internal structure of the file system's notion of a directory too far.

No matter how directories are implemented, the access semantics are as they are *defined* to be – there's really nothing to understand (or, conversely, misunderstand) there; that's just how they are defined to be. The internals of the file system have no bearing on that.

## Personal Remark

I'd note that "the directory is stored as a file" is *one* way a file system might implement directories. It's not the only one. [This](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/login/articles/140-hellwig.pdf) article explains how one of the oldest POSIX-style file systems in the Linux kernel doesn't handle small directory entry lists like files at all – the directory entries aren't stored in data extents, but where usually the list of data extent descriptors would reside for small directories, and for large directories, it's a B+-tree, which itself is stored in extents ([XFS Algorithms & Data Structures 3rd ed](http://ftp.ntu.edu.tw/linux/utils/fs/xfs/docs/xfs_filesystem_structure.pdf), Sec. 17.5 and 16.2) – but nothing like a file as a map of contiguous extents.

So, the assumption "a directory is just a file internally" really doesn't hold.

I honestly don't know when the last time it  held – XFS is from 1993/94, and has been in Linux for 22 years now; ext3 and subsequently ext4 have a similar tree-of-blocks-approach to directory, as well, and ext3 has been around also since ca 2001. I honestly don't know whether thinking about ext2 makes much sense here – I've not set up an ext2 file system since ca 2008, since ext3 without journalling is always a strict advantage over that, and I see Linux distros and embedded tools tend to see it the same way.

Comment: humdedum. About ext3/ext4 vs. ext2, isn't the difference between the linear and hash/tree-based directories just about the internal contents of the directory (file) data? Not the way the directory data blocks are stored in the filesystem? The [filesystem layout](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Hash_Tree_Directories) docs mention e.g. that a struct dx_entry in the directory structure contains a "Block number (_within the directory file_) of the next node" and it even talks about backwards read-only compatibility with ext2!

Comment: (Now, I still don't see what that "everything is a file" has to do with the original question they posted. I suppose on the filesystem level, directories would need to contain the filenames and inode numbers of their contained files, _even if_ the directory itself was stored in some special way completely different from regular files. But for generality, esp. with allowing arbitrary nesting levels, it does seem to make lots of sense to store directories exactly like files as far as possible. Though, returning the inode numbers to userspace from `readdir()` might not be that necessary.)

Comment: deedledumdum! Hm, I skimmed https://web.archive.org/web/20190718230754/http://ext2.sourceforge.net/2005-ols/paper-html/node3.html and inferred that the "high fanout factor" of a single 4k block referring to over 500 blocks within that HTree structure as "not structured as a file. Now, you're right, I don't think that interpretation is compatible with the assumption of ext2 read compatibility. Huh! (Regarding "everything is a file": I'm really not a fan of claiming it's a UNIX mantra or something similar. If that was the case, why does POSIX 2001 still specify so many not-file calls for …

Comment: … operations that could well be file operations. `sleep`? should be a `select` with a timeout if everything's a file! `signal`s? Hm, that doesn't fit the whole everything-is-a-file (eisaf)-philosophy at all; a reasonable everything eisaf programming interface would be designed on non-blocking file IO with preemptable `select` calls on a signal FD or something. The fact that sockets get their own namespace breaks eisaf; why is `malloc` so un-file-y?) @ilkkachu (Not even talking about implementations; if Linux cared about eisaf, what's up with netlink?)

Comment: well, `malloc()` is wholly a user-space construct, though, so I'd exempt that. :) `sleep()` could be implemented as a `write()` to a special file that just takes a varying time to complete depending on what you wrote there, and similarly `gettimeofday()` should be replaced with a `read()` of a similar special file... Yes, some sockets have their own namespace*s*, and worse, the ones that _do_ share the filesystem namespace can't be `open()`ed... Oh but a mantra it still is, sadly, just not a very accurate one, but one that people should be, hmm, taught to leave behind (to put it nicely).

Comment: well, POSIX doesn't really care about whether something is a userland API or a syscall – it says "here's a function you can call". So, when you exempt `malloc` on that basis, you'd need to basically exclude the whole of the POSIX API! (By the way, the `brk` man page specifically tells me to use `malloc`, as `brk` was removed from POSIX) (but we do seem to agree in principle about everything, the universe and stuff)

Comment: The socket issue: "Everything is a file; some files are just more file than others."

Comment: hmmh, yes, true... maybe it's just my old habits raising their heads and preventing me from fully embracing the spirit of eisaf. I shall attempt to mend my ways...

Comment: please stay on your path :) there's so much beauty here in the sun of not gaf about eisaf!

Comment: anyway... that ext4 doc describes a few of the directory structures with references to filesystem data blocks, like how "Interior nodes [are] also the full length of a data block", so it's not like they're fully disconnected. But then it makes sense, since directory handling is a bit more tightly tied with the filesystem operations that some random old text file is, and the FS developers are smart enough to realize that there might be performance benefits in doing full-block accesses. Which is probably something userland databases may also think of.

Answer (score -5):

It is like at the dog park: Everything is a dog. This does not mean that there is one regular dog, and the others are just this dog but with different masks on. It means they all have some sort of dog property.

- They all have names.
- They can all have their name changed.
- They all hangout in a dog-park / directory.
- They can be teleported to another directory (on the same file-system).
- They all contain data (but not necessarily in the same way). Some files are more like others than others. Such as a block device file is more like a regular file than to a directory. Both regular files and block devices are like pipes, streams, sockets, and character devices (but not the other way around).

There are a set of interfaces that a file may have. These include (I probably missed something):

- A file name, (lives in the directory tree): block device, character device, regular file, directory, symlink, named pipe, named socket.
- Sequential readable/writable: pipe, socket, character device, block device, character device, regular file, named pipe, named socket,
- Random accessible: regular file, block device.

I missed out stuff in `/proc`, stuff in `/sys`, stuff in `/net`. These are pretending to be the others.

Comment: You forgot links! Hardlinks: some of suspiciously similar dogs are in fact one dog. You can duplicate any dog, and kill all but one of the clones without any harm to _the_ dog that they all _is_. Softlinks: other dogs, yes, those that don't look exactly opaque, are only looking like dogs, but in fact point to other dogs. And these, transparent, almost invisible dogs, are similar, but are pointing to dogs that in fact don't exist, or unmounted, or even may have never existed! Someone told me, there once was a dog that pointed to itself, but when they looked at it, the Matrix rebooted...